# History of least upper bound property

Tags: math-history

Does anyone know of a good historical account of the Least Upper Bound Property?

I am specifically interested to find out if Gauss knew/discovered some version of it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a very good source of information about the supremun in Chapter XII, Real Numbers, of "Elements of History of Mathematics" by Nicolas Bourbaki  in which the name of Simon Stevin (1548-1620) is noted as the first to conceive clearly the theorem of Bolzano (1781-1848).

And a very interesting study of the subject in http://www.redalyc.org/articulo.oa?id=33560301

(This is the paper in Spanish,  “Completitud y continuidad revisadas a través de 23 siglos”, por Analía Bergé and Carmen Sessa; Revista Latinoamericana de Investigación en Matemática Educativa).